# SSL Certificate Request Failed. Unable to export CNAME records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

I got my rails 5 app hosted on Amazon EC2 and Elastic Beanstalk today, and wanted to add an SSL certificate through Amazon ACM. I want the app to be a little more secure because some of the data the app will use is sensitive. I went through the normal process to get an SSL certificate by going to ACM and clicking on "Request a public certificate" but I'm getting an error that says this:

Request failed
The status of this certificate request is "Failed". Additional verification required to request certificates for one or more domain names in this request.

And then later: 
Unable to export CNAME records

I'm really new to deploying rails applications (like day 1) so here's some things I did that may have impacted this:

1. My instance is being served through EC2. I made an environment on Elastic Beanstalk during some early attempts and used the EC2 instance created with Elastic Beanstalk to try to get it to work.
2. I'm serving the app by SSH-ing into the EC2 instance and running the command "rails s" on the command line of the EC2 instance, then leaving it alone. I troubleshooted until it was serving on localhost:3000 and am accessing the app directly from "mywebsite_name_here.com:3000"
3. My app is in production, not development.

Any tips would be great, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

*Additional verification required to request certificates for one or more domain names in this request.*

This is a documented error.

You are requesting a certificate for a domain that the system has concluded you either can't possibly own (e.g. because Amazon owns it, such as amazonaws.com), or that ACM has otherwise determined requires additional scrutiny for security reasons (e.g. it's a well-known domain).  The logic of this pre-validation step is not public information, to my knowledge.

If you don't have unequivocal control of the domain in question, you need to request a certificate for a domain that is yours.  Otherwise, you'll need to engage AWS Support.

> **Additional Verification Required**
>
> ACM requires additional information to process this certificate request. To provide this information, use the Support Center to contact AWS Support. If you don't have a support plan, post a new thread in the AWS Certificate Manager discussion forum.
>
> **Note**
>
> You cannot request a certificate for Amazon-owned domain names such as those ending in amazonaws.com, cloudfront.net, or elasticbeanstalk.com.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-requests.html#failed-additional-verification-required

Comment: Thanks for your help, mine definitely ends in .elasticbeanstalk.com, so I guess I can't request a certificate. What would you suggest? Do I need to purchase a custom domain name in order to get an SSL then?

Comment: Hey Parzival! Did you purchase a domain or there's another way?